# Angular 5: How to set element attribute value dynamically... Can't bind to 'parent_id' since it isn't a known property of a

Tags: angular

## My Component

```
const activeEl = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.side-navi a.active');
const active_parent_id = activeEl.getAttribute('parent_id');
```

## My Template

```
<a [parent_id]="parent.id"></a>
```

//Can't bind to 'parent_id' since it isn't a known property of a...

```
<a parent_id="{{parent.id}}"></a>
```

//Can't bind to 'parent_id' since it isn't a known property of a...

```
<a parent_id="parent.id"></a>
```

// component returns "**parent.id**" (string)

## Question

How do i set the attribute, `parent_id` with `{{parent.id}}` so that it can be used in my component like `el.getAttribute('parent_id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Adding Custom attribute in Angular

Try it like this. with `attr.`

`<a [attr.parent_id]="parent.id"></a>`